# SPSS error when running for manova

Tags: spss, two-way

I have been having problems with SPSS. When I try to run a data set it says:

```
>Error # 12005 in column 14.  Text: -4
>A parenthesized value range in the MANOVA procedure contains a lower limit
>(the first value) that is greater than the upper limit (the second value).
>Execution of this command stops.
```

This is the syntax that I am trying to run:

```
manova P_Progress, P_ObsComp, P_SocFdBk, P_PsyState
by Group4 (1,2,3,4) Group3 (1,2,3)/
print=cellinfo(means)
     homogeneity(all)
     error(cor)
     signif(multiv,univ,stepdown)/
omean=variables(P_Progress, P_ObsComp, P_SocFdBk, P_PsyState) tables(Group4, 
Group3)/plot=normal.
```

I am working on a two way manova.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise to consult the IBM SPSS Statistics Syntax Reference regarding the MANOVA. The syntax of MANOVA should be like this:

```
MANOVA dependent varlist [BY factor list (min,max)[factor list...]
[WITH covariate list]]
```

I believe this code should work:

```
manova P_Progress, P_ObsComp, P_SocFdBk, P_PsyState
    by Group4 (1,4) Group3 (1,3)
  /print = cellinfo(means)
    homogeneity(all)
    error(cor)
    signif(multiv,univ,stepdown)
  /omean = variables(P_Progress, P_ObsComp, P_SocFdBk, P_PsyState)
    tables(Group4, Group3)
  /plot=normal.
```